# Using sed -i to run consecutive command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sed

I have an sh file (named `a.sh`) and I process it with the command `sbatch` for my project, so I type a lot of:

```
sbatch a.sh
```

There are 2 critical lines for a.sh (rest of them are irrelevant I guess). They are

source /okyanus/progs/gaussian/g16/bsd/g16.sariyer.profile

and

g16 dtn-b3-0-0.gjf

The second one is at the end of the file (further will be mentioned as aaa.com) and it is what needs to be changed. and aaa.com should be in the same directory with a.sh to submit the job aaa.com.

In the `a.sh` file, there is a name of a file (lets say `aaa.com`) which the data is taken for the `sbatch` process. So a standard operation for me to do lets say next 4 jobs is:

1. modify the `a.sh` file to change the name of the file addressed (say change `aaa.com` to `aab.com`), write and quit
2. type: `sbatch a.sh` (to start operation)
3. modify the `a.sh` file to change the name of the file addressed (say change `aab.com` to `aac.com`), write and quit
4. type: `sbatch a.sh` (to start operation)
5. modify the `a.sh` file to change the name of the file addressed (say change `aac.com` to `aad.com`), write and quit
6. type: `sbatch a.sh` (to start operation)
7. modify the `a.sh` file to change the name of the file addressed (say change `aad.com` to `aae.com`), write and quit
8. type: sbatch `a.sh` (to start operation)

However, I used to have a command template with `sed -i`. That command could do these 8 operations in one tick. From my old notes, I could find some parts of my old template.

my old template is a short version but works effectively to execute first two operations in one step with the command:

```
sed -i 's/aaa.com/aab.com/g' a.sh ; sbatch a.sh
```

above command does first and second step at once. I knew I used a command which could execute all 8 steps at once. I was something like:

```
sed -i 's/aaa.com/aab.com???aab.com/aac.com???aac.com/aad.com???aad.com/aae.com/g' a.sh ; sbatch a.sh
```

The above command could do all 8 steps at once, submitting next 4 jobs. However, I could not remember what should have been written on the ??? parts to successfully execute the command.

I am sure the command I propose worked with its correct state. Any other ideas and helps will be appreciated.

P.S.: a.sh file is something generated from the system. It sources a program related with chemistry, then submits the values of the .com (or .gjf) file to the chemistry program it runs for.

Thanks!

Comment: You could use e.g. a `for` loop. Would it be an option to change the script `a.sh` to take the file to be processed as a command line argument? Then you could call it like `a.sh aaa.com` etc and maybe use `for f in aaa aab aac ; do sbatch a.sh ${f}.com ; done` If you would [edit] your question and show the code in `a.sh` it would be easier to give better suggestions or a full answer.

Comment: If changing `a.sh` is for some reason not an option, then cp `a.sh` to `b.sh` and edit `b.sh`.  It is absurd to continually modify the script.  Use parameters instead.

Comment: If the `sbatch` you're using is the one that accepts the `--input` directive to read stdin for the batch script, perhaps you want to do `sed ... a.sh | sbatch --input` if passing parameters from sbatch is difficult

Comment: Changing a.sh file IS an option. In fact it is the option if we do not have shortcut. I have to modify it maybe 10 times and write sbatch a.sh command after each modification.

The idea here is doing it with one step.

I am trying to win time by doing 20 operations in one step. Why this is absurd?

Comment: Dealing with states is always going to be hard. Instead consider writing a template file and an array with parameters, and instead of _modifying_ the `a.sh` file, _recreate_ the whole file - less state, less problems.

Comment: Hey I have found what my command was. So I write here for data.

There goes command for 3 jobs

sed -i 's/previous.com/first.com/g' a.sh ; sbatch a.sh ; sed -i 's/first.com/second.gjf/g' a.sh ; sbatch a.sh ; sed -i 's/second.gjf/third.com/g' a.sh ; sbatch a.sh

Comment: Leaving the command for community.

KamilCuk - the a.sh is not bugged or long. It just needs to be change for each job. There are sometimes 20 jobs.

-

Bodo your solution seems to be an improvement but as a Linux newbie I do not know what should I change in the sh file.

Answer (score 0):

> what should have been written on the ??? parts to successfully execute the command

`s` or `s/<regex>/<replacement>/<flags>` is a substitute command.

The default and ultimate command separator in sed is *the* newline. Optionally when possible you can separate commands with a `;`. So it looks like:

```
sed 's/regex/replacement/; s/regex2/replacement2/; : another_command ; b another_command'
```

> I was something like:
> sed -i 's/aaa.com/aab.com???aab.com/aac.com???aac.com/aad.com???aad.com/aae.com/g'

Doing:

```
sed 's/aaa.com/aab.com/; s/aab.com/aac.com/;`
```

makes no sense, first `aaa` is replaced by `aab`, then `aab` by `aac`. It's the same as:

```
sed 's/aaa.com/aac.com/;`
```

You can do it from the back:

```
sed 's/aab.com/aac.com/; s/aaa.com/aab.com/;'
```

But really save yourself the trouble of dealing with some uncretain state and create a template file:

```
# template.a.sh
work on UNIQUE_STRING
```

then iterate over values and replace recreating the whole file each time, that way you do not have to care what "was" in the file and what "will be" in the file. Just create the file from template:

```
for i in aaa.com aab.com aac.com; do
    sed 's/UNIQUE_STRING/'"$i"'/' template.a.sh > a.sh
    sbatch a.sh
done
```

Comment: Yes, indeed sed 's/aaa.com/aab.com/; s/aab.com/aac.com/ makes no sense. Because sbatch a.sh command should be put after each change. The correct line for 3 jobs is: sed -i 's/previous.com/first.com/g' a.sh ; sbatch a.sh ; sed -i 's/first.com/second.gjf/g' a.sh ; sbatch a.sh ; sed -i 's/second.gjf/third.com/g' a.sh ; sbatch a.sh.

However, your solution using for command is better. I created a temp.a.sh file but dont know how to modify it to use "for" command you propose. I guess it wont work just the way you write. Would you like me to send you the temp.a.sh file?

Comment: `I guess it wont work just the way you write.` ? why https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/SillyViolentBlock#main.sh

Comment: I am not so sure. Could you please check?
https://repl.it/@Beko2/SillyViolentBlock#my.sh